# jenkins update plugins throws java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ?id=simpleupdatesite&version=2.32.1 (jenkins 2.32.1 version)

Tags: jenkins

http://machine.name.com/pluginManager/advanced
and I hit submit on the update site url (http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json) I get the following error

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ?id=simpleupdatesite&version=2.32.1
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:585)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:180)
    at hudson.PluginManager.doCheckUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1619)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:335)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:52)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:175)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:108)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$2.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:174)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter$1.call(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:49)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter$1.call(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:44)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.ScmSyncConfigurationDataProvider.provideRequestDuring(ScmSyncConfigurationDataProvider.java:106)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.doFilter(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:44)
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having exactly same problem and after checking Jenkins source code I found the root cause was in **JENKINS_HOME/hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml** having url element empty for default site:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sites>
  <site>
    <id>default</id>
    <url>http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json</url>
  </site>
</sites>
```

So, just fill with default url above or your plugins update repository.